# Is a direct assignment of a volatile variable thread safe? As safe as an AtomicReference?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

Is this as safe as using an AtomicReference?

```
private volatile String myMember;

public void setMyMember(String s) { 
   myMember = s;
}
```

vs.

```
private final AtomicReference<String> myMember = new AtomicReference<>();

public void setMyMember(String s) {
    while (true) {
        String current = myMember.get();
        if (myMember.compareAndSet(current, s))
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: your entire second example method is equivalent to `myMember.set(s)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is "safe" but doesn't do the same thing as the `AtomicReference` code.  Typically, the `AtomicReference` loop with `compareAndSet` is used when someone is trying to add something to a list or object and they want to protect against the race conditions with multiple threads.

For example:

```
private final AtomicReference<List<String>> listRef = new AtomicReference<>();
...
while (true) {
    List<String> currentList = listRef.get();
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(currentList);
    newList.add(stringToAdd);
    // if we update the list reference, make sure we don't overwrite another one
    if (listRef.compareAndSet(currentList, newList))
        break;
}
```

In your case, since you are using a simple `String` object, just making it `volatile` will be fine.  There is no point in doing the `compareAndSet`.  If you still want to use `AtomicReference`, then just call `myMember.set(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your first code snippet is completely thread safe and is enough because `String` is thread safe and assigning to variable is atomic.

The second one doesn't make much sense, such construct is used internally e.g. in `AtomicInteger` to avoid ignoring assignments in concurrent environment. `volatile` is fine in your case.